# MYSQL ePHP- Tenho um produto que possui várias revisões e quero pegar a maior revisão

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
TABLE REVISAO_1

| ID | REVISÃO | DATA 
| 1  | G       | 01/01/2023 
| 1  | Z       | 01/03/2023 
| 1  | AA      | 01/10/2022 

TABLE REVISAO_2 
| ID | REVISÃO | DATA 
| 1  | L       | 09/01/2023 
| 1  | AP      | 09/03/2023 
| 1  | AD      | 09/04/2023
```

quero pegar a máxima revisão, que seria a do dia 01/10/2022 e 09/03/2023 e a data mais recente. A data mais recente ok, a função MAX me atende, só que quando uso a função MAX para a revisão mais recente, ele me retorna a revisão Z e L, pois é a maior na tabela ASCII.

exemplo:

```
SELECT 
   R1.id, 
   max(R1.revisao) as rev1, 
   max(R2.revisao) as rev2, 
   max(R1.data) as data1, 
   max(R2.data) as data2 
FROM 
   revisao_1 as R1 
INNER JOIN 
   revisao_2 as R2 ON (R2.id = R1.id) 
WHERE 
   R1.id = '1' 
GROUP BY 
   R1.id;
```

Só que ai ele me retorna:

```
TABLE REVISAO 
| ID | REVISÃO1 | DATA 1     | REVISAO 2 | DATA 2 
| 1  | Z        | 01/03/2023 | L         | 09/04/2023
```

Gostaria que me retornasse

```
TABLE REVISAO 
| ID | REVISÃO1 | DATA 1     | REVISAO 2 | DATA 2 
| 1  | AA       | 01/03/2023 | AP        | 09/04/2023
```

PS. Posso também manipular com uma função PHP mas não consegui pensar em uma.

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta e foram passados 2 links que em tese resolvem o seu caso. Seria importante uma verificada nos links. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/581074 - E caso por alguma razão não servirem, o que é improvável, foram dadas as instruções de como proceder para reconsideração da pergunta (editando e explicando o que tem de diferente no seu caso). Para evitar duplicação de orientações o espaço de comentários foi desativado, mas pode ser usado na sua [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/581074) (restaurando-a se necessário)